# How can I vectorized the below python pandas code?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

This is a trailing stoploss function that is working fine. But it's taking too long time to calculate. I want to convert it into vectorized code. How is that possible?

```
df['LSL'] = df.Close * 0.98
df['Long_TSL'] = df['LSL']

for i in range(1,len(df)):

    if df['Long_TSL'][i-1] > df['LSL'][i]:
        df['Long_TSL'][i] = df['Long_TSL'][i-1]
```

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example of the input data and the matching expected output

Comment: I'd use a combination of `numpy.where` and `pandas.Series.shift`

Comment: I have solved that problem myself.......df['Long_TSL'] = df.Close.cummax() * 0.98